# PHP - mysqli_num_rows - Saying I only have 1 row when I have many rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display the number of rows in a table using mysqli_num_rows. When I print the results, it says I only have 1 row, when I really have several rows.

When I tested the SQL in phpMyAdmin, it counts the correct number of rows. But when I display the results on my web page, it counts only one row.

Please help me. What I am doing wrong?

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "myusername", "mypass", "mydatabase");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

    /* close result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
```

The above codes prints the following, no matter how many rows I have:

Result set has 1 rows.

Comment: remove the count function. it's one or the other

Comment: To elaborate on Fred's comment, `COUNT` is one of many aggregate functions which work on 'groups' of rows. In your query, the `COUNT` automatically 'collapses' all the rows into a single row for the group. Your group in this case contains all rows.

Comment: Thanks guys. Got it working.

Answer (score 3):

The result of a simple `COUNT(*)` statement is always one row. You want to fetch that row and get the value returned from the first column.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when you use **COUNT**, the result of the query is the number of rows.
I usually try to write the sql query straight to **phpmyadmin** to see what happens. It would reveal the mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this if the database i small.

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM mytable")) {

    /* determine number of rows result set */
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;

    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt);

    /* close result set */
    $result->close();
}
```

With i big database you could be doing like this as mentioned in the comments. I'm not so good with PDO or object oriented requests so this will be procedural.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row[0]);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: The downside to doing it this way is that you're returning the whole recordset - if you leave the `SELECT count(*)` in, you're returning a single row. For smaller databases, there's little difference, but when you've got a couple of million rows, it's a lot more efficient to have the database do the sums for you.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I did. It's a small database.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "myusername", "mypass", "mydatabase");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$sql="SELECT * FROM mytable";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Use mysqli_num_rows() method to fetch number of rows in the resultset.

Refer link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php